# How to filter the products that can be added to an Order?

Tags: pricebook, order, product

Begining to look at Orders and Products and I have a very basic question:

How can you filter the Products that are available on an Order?

All of our accounts can create an order, we have various order record types to distinguish the type of order and this will ultimately lead to a very specific set of products that can be related...

Thanks

EDIT: Would adding a price book for each record type and then associating this price book to that order record type work.

Comment: price book doesn't governed by recordtype

Comment: You can view the products in Order Line Items. How you want to achieve through reports or SOQL query?

Comment: Not sure i follow! this is whilst a user is completing an order?

Answer (score 2):

Orders can be implemented in a number of different ways. Some orgs will use Opportunity to create a Contract and then create Orders against the Contract. One can associate a Price Book with a Contract and each order will use that Price Book by default. You'll want to use Record Types for Orders, NOT for Price Books.

If you decided to use Contracts, just like Opportunity, you can assign a Record Type to the Contract which would provide something of an implicit record type association with the Price Book, but not an explicit one.

What I'd recommend is for you to look at Business Processes and define a Business Process for each type of Order. You've already done part of that by using Record Types. If appropriate, you *could* extend what you've done by requiring certain Price Books if you wanted to for each Business Process.

For more on implementing Orders, see [Setting Up Salesforce Orders for Your Organization](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/20/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_orders_cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, primarily our users are Service cloud users and they will be taking the orders. We won't be using contracts but I think the business process is a way forward